# How to list data-tz in drop down in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.btn-secondary').html(selText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
  <button id="startHour" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Zone</button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="zone">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="est">America/New_York</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="cst">America/Chicago</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="mst">America/Devner</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="pst">America/Los_Angeles</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am listing **zone name** in drop down but I need to display abbreviate name of zone.
Here is the html code I used:

```
<div id="zone" class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown">zone</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="zone">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="est">America/New_York</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="cst">America/Chicago</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="mst">America/Devner</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="pst">America/Los_Angeles</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code used to display selected in button. Here is the code I used:

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    var currentBtn = $(this).closest(".btn-group").children("button");
    var currentUnit = currentBtn.data("unit");
    currentBtn.html(selText);
    console.log(currentUnit);
    $("."+ currentUnit).text(selText);
});
```

How can I list data-tz-abbrev in drop down instead of displaying america/chicago in drop down?

Comment: When generating dropdown use time zone abbreviation as text instead of actual name.

Comment: what is it that you are doing exactly? and what is to be done? With your code I am not able to make head or tail of it

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Right now when i click on zone button, it list america/chicago in drop down list. Instead of list that i need to list est, mst in drop down

Comment: See, with your provided code, there is no dropdown or anything, when we simply copy paste your html and JS , both button and the hyperlinks are visible. The click event is not even getting triggered.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt check out snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the dropdown item's text on the click event of the zone button.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  var selText = $(this).text();
  var currentBtn = $(this).closest(".btn-group").children("button");
  var currentUnit = currentBtn.data("unit");
  currentBtn.html(selText);
  console.log(currentUnit);
  $("." + currentUnit).text(selText);
});

$("#zone button").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-item").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr('data-tz-abbrev')); // Set the option text using data-tz-abbrev attribute.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zone" class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- toggle="dropdown">zone</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="zone">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="est">America/New_York</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="cst">America/Chicago</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="mst">America/Devner</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tz-abbrev="pst">America/Los_Angeles</a>
  </div>
</div>
```